# How to Add User Information to nlog Error Logging

Tags: c#, exception, nlog, asp.net-core-3.1, error-logging

I have started using nLog to log errors on my application recently. However, I am here to see if there is any way to add some information about the currently logged in user on the application to the log layout if a user is currently logged in on the application at the time the exception occurs.

Currently I have the following layout:

```
<target xsi:type="File" name="errorlogs" fileName="./logs/error-logs/${shortdate}.log"
        layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}|url: ${aspnet-request-url}|action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}" />
```

However, I wish to add the email of the currently logged in user if the exception happens when there is a logged in user on the application.

My application is running on ASP.Net Core 3.1.

How can I add that to the layout.

Thank you

Comment: Is the email available through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimtypes.email ? This pull-request will add support for user-claim-lookup: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/pull/609 Remember GDPR-rules :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not a 100% fit as your question relies on the User logging into your application, and your application running under their user context, but the following works for me in 'normal' application programming...

Create a new public static class.  I call mine "Logging".
If your assembly doesn't have it already, add a reference to NLog.

The output format is that used by the freely available Microsoft CMTrace utility.  Available here: [CMTrace Download link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e15c1000-9e3a-4bfc-8b03-16bcf415b39f/cmtrace-download-link?forum=configmanagergeneral)

Add the following:

```
    public static class Logging
{
    #region Fields

    private static bool _IsSetup = false;
    private static Logger _Log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    #endregion

    #region Private Methods

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    private static string GetCurrentMethod()
    {
        StackTrace st = new StackTrace();
        int FrameNumber = 1;
        StackFrame sf = st.GetFrame(FrameNumber);  // Get the previous stack frame
        string MethodName = sf.GetMethod().Name;
        string ClassName = sf.GetMethod().ReflectedType.FullName;

        while (MethodName == "Log" || MethodName.StartsWith("Write")) // If it's the "Log" or "Write" method calling this, get the method before that one.
        {
            FrameNumber++;

            if (FrameNumber < 6)
            {
                try
                {
                    MethodName = st.GetFrame(FrameNumber).GetMethod().Name;
                    ClassName = st.GetFrame(FrameNumber).GetMethod().ReflectedType.FullName;
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
            else // Prevent an infinite loop
            {
                MethodName = "Unknown Method";
                ClassName = "Unknown Class";
            }
        }
        return ClassName + "." + MethodName;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Append the specified text to the given TextBox
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Message">The message to append</param>
    /// <param name="Control">The TextBox to target</param>
    public static void LogToTextbox(string Message, TextBox Control)
    {
        if (Message.Length > 0)
        {
            Control.AppendText(Message + Environment.NewLine);
            Control.Refresh();
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Setup Logging
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Overwrite">If set to true, any existing file will be over-written</param>
    public static void Setup(bool Overwrite = false)
    {
        LoggingConfiguration Config = new LoggingConfiguration();
        FileTarget File = new FileTarget();

        Config.AddTarget("File", File);
        File.Layout = "${message}";
        File.FileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData), Application.CompanyName, System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName) + ".log";
        File.AutoFlush = true;
        File.KeepFileOpen = false;
        File.ArchiveFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData), Application.CompanyName, System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName) + "_{#}.log";
        File.ArchiveNumbering = ArchiveNumberingMode.Rolling;
        File.ArchiveEvery = FileArchivePeriod.Day;
        File.MaxArchiveDays = 31;

        if (Overwrite)
        {
            File.DeleteOldFileOnStartup = true;
        }

        // Create rules
        LoggingRule Rule1 = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Trace, File);

        // Apply rules
        Config.LoggingRules.Add(Rule1);

        // Activate logging
        LogManager.Configuration = Config;

        // Cleanup

        _IsSetup = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Write the specified message type and string to the logfile, located at %PROGRAMDATA/[Application.CompanyName]
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Level">The level of message to write</param>
    /// <param name="Message">The message to write</param>
    public static void Write(LogLevel Level, string Message)
    {
        string Severity;
        string OutputMessage;
        DateTime UtcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
        DateTime Now = DateTime.Now;
        string UtcDate = UtcNow.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
        string UtcTime = UtcNow.ToString("HH:mm:ss.") + UtcNow.Millisecond;
        string Date = Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
        string Time = Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.") + UtcNow.Millisecond;
        string TZOffset = TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(Now).TotalHours.ToString("+000");

        if (!_IsSetup)
        {
            Setup();
        }

        Trace.WriteLine(Message);

        Message = $"{Date} {Time}: {Message}";

        switch (Level.Name)
        {
            default:
                Severity = "0";
                break;
            case "Info":
                Severity = "1";
                break;
            case "Warn":
                Severity = "2";
                break;
            case "Error":
                Severity = "3";
                break;
        }

        // https://adamtheautomator.com/building-logs-for-cmtrace-powershell/

        OutputMessage = $"<![LOG[{Message}]LOG]!><time=\"{UtcTime}{TZOffset}\" date=\"{UtcDate}\" component=\"{GetCurrentMethod()}\" context=\"{Environment.UserName}\" type=\"{Severity}\" thread=\"{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}\" file=\"{System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName}\">";

        // The following can be used as a catch-all

        //try
        //{
        _Log.Log(Level, OutputMessage);
        //}
        //catch (Exception e)
        //{
        //    // If we cannot write to the log file, write to the EventLog instead.
        //    using (EventLog eventLog = new EventLog("Application"))
        //    {
        //        string OutputFolderName = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData), Application.CompanyName);
        //        string ExecutableName = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;

        //        eventLog.Source = "Application";
        //        eventLog.WriteEntry($"Failed to write to application logfile (in {OutputFolderName}) for {ExecutableName}.  The error was: {e.Message}", EventLogEntryType.Error, 101, 1);
        //    }
        //}
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Write a error message to the logfile, located at %PROGRAMDATA/[Application.CompanyName]
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Message">The message to write</param>
    public static void WriteError(string Message)
    {
        Write(LogLevel.Error, Message);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Write an informational message to the logfile, located at %PROGRAMDATA/[Application.CompanyName]
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Message">The message to write</param>
    public static void WriteInfo(string Message)
    {
        Write(LogLevel.Info, Message);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Write a warning message to the logfile, located at %PROGRAMDATA/[Application.CompanyName]
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Message">The message to write</param>
    public static void WriteWarning(string Message)
    {
        Write(LogLevel.Warn, Message);
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Usage:

```
Logging.Setup();

Logging.WriteInfo("Application startup");

Logging.WriteError($"{DestinationFilename}: Cannot overwrite file.  User advised to delete file manually.  The error was: {ex.Message}");
```

Example output:

```
<![LOG[20-11-2020 13:22:48.626: Application startup]LOG]!><time="05:22:48.626+008" date="11-20-2020" component="Bitberry.Elda.GetLatest.frmMain..ctor" context="DaveR" type="1" thread="1" file="GetLatest">
```

Specifically, the 'context="USERNAME"' portion is what you have asked for.

Comment: Think the original question was logging the email of the used logged on a AspNet-website. `Environment.UserName` will return the service-account / user-account of the running application (Matches NLog `${environment-user}`)

Comment: You should consider making use of NLog LayoutRenderers to perform context-capture. Then your code-piece could be reduced to a single NLog-Layout-line.

Comment: Thanks @RolfKristensen.  Please note that I covered your point (in your first comment) in my first paragraph (or at least, I tried to)